# Método Sort da minha flatList

Tags: javascript, json, react, react-native

```
 <FlatList
                style={{backgroundColor: 'white', marginTop: 10}}
                data={this.state.progr.data.sort((a, b) => a.start_time > b.start_time).filter(x => x.period === '2019-10-17T00:00:00.000-03:00')}
                renderItem={({item}) => this.renderItem({item})}
                keyExtractor = {(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
            />
```

O start_time que está sendo ordenado, me retorna uma data JSON, dessa forma 2019-09-10T14:00:00.000-03:00".
Quero ordenar apenas pela hora.

Já tentei da seguinte forma:

```
<FlatList
                style={{backgroundColor: 'white', marginTop: 10}}
                data={this.state.progr.data.sort((a, b) => a.(new Date(start_time).getHours()) > b.(new Date(start_time).getHours()).filter(x => x.period === '2019-10-17T00:00:00.000-03:00')}
                renderItem={({item}) => this.renderItem({item})}
                keyExtractor = {(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
            />
```

Tentei assim e não deu crt.
Alguém pode me ajudar na sintaxe por favor?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ordenar pela hora usa este código similar ao que eu te mandei antes por data:

```js
let listaRecebida = [
 {"period": "2019-10-19T19:00:00.000-03:00"},
 {"period": "2019-10-11T11:00:00.000-03:00"},
 {"period": "2019-10-16T16:00:00.000-03:00"},
 {"period": "2019-10-13T13:00:00.000-03:00"},
 {"period": "2019-10-27T07:00:00.000-03:00"},
 {"period": "2019-10-19T19:03:00.000-03:00"},
 {"period": "2019-10-19T19:01:00.000-03:00"},
 {"period": "2019-10-19T19:02:00.000-03:00"},
];

function apenasHoras(dataStr) {
  const data = new Date(dataStr);
  const horas = data.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const minutos = data.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const segundos = data.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  return `${horas}${minutos}${segundos}`;
}

listaOrdenada = listaRecebida.sort(
 function(a, b){
   const varA = apenasHoras(a.period);
   const varB = apenasHoras(b.period);
   return varA-varB;
  }
)

console.log('Lista ordenada');
listaOrdenada.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item.period);
});
```

Quero te dar 2 observações/indicações:

1. Faça a ordenação ao receber o objeto e não na renderização do mesmo.
2. Não se usa filter para ordenar. Filter como o nome diz, é para filtrar, ou seja, só vai ser exibido os itens que retornam positivo na rotina do filter.

Qualquer dúvida estamos aê.

Comment: O filter não está sendo usado para ordenar, está sendo usado para filtrar msm. Pois o JSON (q n foi criado por mim) tem um item para a data, um item para a hr inicial, e um outro para a hr final

Comment: Se vc observar no código acima, o sort é usado com o 'start_time' e o filter com o 'period'. São distintos

Comment: Tô fznd a ordenação na renderização, pois na folha tem 4 flatList... todas renderizadas com um filter diferente